# SSIS 2008 determine source column from destination column (programatically)

Tags: ssis

Not sure if there's any way to do this, but we're trying to programmatically determine dependencies in our ETL process, specifically whether modifying a column in our source data set will impact our ETLs and if so, which ones, ie. with a package 'myPackage' containing a data flow task that draws from 'sourceTable' and includes various columns including 'column1' and ultimately loads 'destinationTable' with 'column1New' is there any way to query the SSIS package itself to determine that column1New is based on column1 (does lineage provide anything of use here?)

Answer (score 0):

Each column you use in a transformation of your package is associated an ID. The next component to which the column is passed down to will refer to that column using the lineage ID property, but is given a new id.

You could query the XML of your package to trace the path a column takes by creating a map of these IDs. However, this might be difficult to implement in a stable way.

This might help you on your way:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/helloworld/archive/2008/08/01/how-to-find-out-which-column-caused-ssis-to-fail.aspx